# How to change Toggle Value for only 1 row not all

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a mat-toggle as a column in Mat-table.I am changing values on toggle on/off. However the issue is if I change the value then the value changes for all the rows. I want to do it only for the particular row. How can I do it.

HTML Code:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="active">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Reschedule</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <mat-slide-toggle (change)="setMessage($event)">{{
      message
    }}</mat-slide-toggle>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

Typescript Code:

```
// Toggle Button Code
message = 'Disabled!';
setMessage(e) {
    if (e.checked) {
        this.message = 'Running';
    } else {
        this.message = 'Disabled!';
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to define a property on element which holds the message and only toggle the property for this element.

Answer (score 2):

You need a property for **every row** to bind your toggle state to.

E.g.:

Component data:

```
....
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H', activate: true, role: '1' },
...
```

Template:

```
...
    <!-- toggle olumn -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="toggle">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> toggle </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" >
            <mat-slide-toggle [checked]="element.activate" (change)="updateActiveStatus(element)"></mat-slide-toggle>
        </td>
    </ng-container>
...
```

Check this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-toggle-4rwiww?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html) for a working version.

Comment: What if the data is coming from an API and doesn't contain activate:true value. Do I need to change the backend or is there alternate way.

Comment: Depends on what you want to archive. Is your value only needed in the frontend and not used in the backend...